# TensorBoard: What's the difference between the time series and scalars tabs?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I'm using tensorboard 2.11.2. I don't understand the difference between the time series and scalars tabs.
I read in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorboard-in-5-minutes-71c5715a10d3) article that the only difference between them is that time series is used to display metrics in each iteration while scalars only display information at the end of each epoch.

- Is this true? Are there any other differences between the two tabs?
- Why there isn't an option for downloading figures as images in the time series tab? You can do that on the scalars tab.

Tried browsing on the internet but the only somewhat useful looking information I found was the linked article and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras) tensorboard tutorial in tensorflow docs. Also asked chatgpt. I still don't understand the difference.

Comment: Both tabs serve different purposes and offer distinct visualizations. The Scalars tab is suitable for monitoring individual scalar metrics, while the Time Series tab is more appropriate for analyzing and comparing multiple time series data. Depending on your needs and the type of data you want to visualize, you can choose the appropriate tab in TensorBoard.